# Utilizing memory to its fullest in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have running a Pyspark application and I am trying to persist dataframe as I am using the dataframe again in the code.

I am using the following:

`sourceDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)`

I am processing 30GB of data. 
I have 3 nodes, all 16 GB RAM and 4 Virtual Cores.
From Spark UI, I see the Size in Memory after persistence is very less. I'd want it to store the cached data in RAM Memory as much as possible.

[image]

How can I best utilise RAM Memory?

Also, the GC time for the tasks seems quite high. How can I reduce it ?

[image]

Comment: [`DataFrame.cache()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#cache())

Comment: Dataframe.cache() will try to store all data in RAM memory. Considering, i only have limited memory and processing 30GB of data, I can't use `cache()` or `df.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)` I believe?

Answer (score 0):

You're already making the best use of memory by using dataframes and storing data with serialization.  There's not much more you can do besides filtering out as much data as possible that isn't needed for the final result before caching.

Garbage collection is tricky.  When working with Dataframe API and untyped transformations, catalyst is going to do its best to avoid unnecessary object creation.  You really don't have much of a say when using dataframes and running into GC issues.  Some operations are inherently more expensive as far as performance and object creation, but you can only control those using the typed dataset api and rdd api.  You're best off doing what you're currently doing now.  If GC is truly an issue, the best thing you can do is use a JVM profiling tool and find which pieces of code are creating the most objects and looking to optimize that.  In addition, trying to minimize as much as possible data skew, and leveraging broadcast joins where possible should help avoid some GC.

Comment: Thanks Joe. If i look at storage memory, it is only about 694.8 mB of the total 26 GB assigned. I thought it can be utilised further for better performance?

Comment: Is the data in uncompressed csv files?  The serialized columnar storage in spark sql can compress the data quite a bit.  10x is not surprising if your going from uncompressed text to compressed + columnar + serialized.

Comment: Hi Joe, the data is in uncompressed csv file and that is expected form of source data. Is the processing of a csv file slow than the table?

Comment: CSV as a file format is much slower than a Parquet file.  Tables in memory on spark are stored in a serialized columnar format similar to parquet.  In a perfect world, your source data would be a parquet file and you'd build a dataframe from that parquet file.